# Assignment to gather upper limits and squared integers

Tags: python

My assignment is:

Please write a program which asks the user to type in an upper limit. The program then prints out numbers so that each subsequent number is the previous one doubled, starting from the number 1. That is, the program prints out powers of two in order.

The execution of the program finishes when the next number to be printed would be greater than the limit set by the user. No numbers greater than the limit should be printed.

Upper limit: 8
1
2
4
8

This is what I've written

```
limit = int(input("Upper limit:"))
number = 0
power = 0
while power < limit:
    number += 1
    power = number ** 2
    print(power)
```

It's almost correct, except it'll print one row too many. For instance, if I input 50, I'll get:

1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64

I know it's because I put while power < limit, but I'm not sure what to do about it.

Edit: Also, I'm supposed to do this without the True conditional.

Comment: Hi, it looks to me like you are getting the powers of all numbers adding from `0 to N**2>= limit`. This is not a sequence of powers of 2 but rather a sequence of squared integers in a range.

To do this, start with `number=1`. get rid of the power variable completely. Then, `while number < limit: number**=2` make sure to put the print function above the calculation function so it breaks the loop if the number is above.

Comment: @josephvictory Thanks! I tried to follow your instructions and came up with this:


`limit = int(input("Upper limit:"))`

`number = 1`

`while number < limit:`
    
`print(number)`
    `number**=2`



And I'm getting an unending loop. What did I do wrong?

Comment: It was a bit annoying to use the comment formatting, so i just wrote a full answer below with explanations to help you figure out the logic a bit more and grow hopefully. Edit: i wrote it wrong, it should be `number*=2` since `1**2 is 1` woops. otherwise your code is correct

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the answer to the problem as written. Specifically you asked. "The program then prints out numbers so that each subsequent number is the previous one doubled, starting from the number 1."

First, assign a value of 1 to the number variable `number = 1`. Then, since each number is a doubling of the previous number you want to assign the multiple of the number variable to number, overwriting it `number*=2`. The numbers will increase as so: 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128.

If you want to avoid printing the number that breaks the limit. You need to put print above the calculation. This is so that it always prints the previous value of number and not the next value which at the end, will always be over the limit.

```
limit = int(input("Upper limit:"))
number = 1
while number <= limit:
    print(number) # print must be before the calculation to ensure it breaks loop without printing the first number above the limit
    number *= 2 # multiply and operator. number *= 2 means number = number*2
```

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown. When I use this code I get a NameError for line 5 "power is not defined." What's supposed to be in that print function?

Comment: Lol no worries. Thanks for your help. One thing to add, it should also included powers of 2 equal to the input, so a small change I had to make was `while number <= limit:`

Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, ill edit it to reflect, just remember to select an answer to close the question! (i get points for helping if you choose my answer ect, so its important to do it, gl!)

Comment: I'm confused, this does not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! You could use a `break` statement, which exits the loop when executed by the program, like below:

```py
while True:
    number += 1
    power = number ** 2
    if power < limit:
        print(power)
    else:
        break
```

The loop in this example will continue forever or until the `break statement` because of the `while True:` line. This means it will keep executing until the limit is reached. I hope this answers your question!

Comment: True, I guess I worded it badly. Editing to reflect.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I should have mentioned, the exercise specifically said not to use True as the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can either divide the limit by 2 or just change the starting variables like so:

```
limit = int(input("Upper limit:"))
number = 1
power = 1
while power < limit:
    print(power)
    number += 1
    power = number ** 2
```

Comment: This doesn't print the first value of the number. The result for 50 with this is ```2 4 9 16 25 36 49```.

Comment: Sorry, number should be 1 at first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use log_2(limit) as like:

```
import math 
limit = int(input("Upper limit:"))
n = int(math.log(limit, 2)) + 1
for i in range(n):
    print(pow(2,i))
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>Most simple way:</s>

One of possible ways:

```
limit = int(input("Upper limit:"))

BASE = 2
i = 0

while BASE ** i <= limit:
  print(BASE ** i)
  i += 1
```

```
Upper limit:8
1
2
4
8
```